# inotify not registering all events

Tags: c++, c, docker, ubuntu, inotify

I'm trying to watch a directory recursively with inotify, meaning, I want to be notified whenever a directory or file is created inside this directory or in one of the subdirectories. The main directory is empty at the start of the program.

I basically copied the code from here for testing: https://gist.github.com/pkrnjevic/6016356

Now, when I run the application and start populating the watched directory, inotify only registers the creation of a direct subdirectory and the first subsubdirectory, any files inside the subdirectory or other subsubdirectories are not registered.
I will try to illustrate:

```
/home/user/watched_directory: echo "hello" > file.txt               // registered by inotify
/home/user/watched_directory: mkdir subdir                          // registered by inotify
/home/user/watched_directory: mkdir subdir/subsubdir                // registered by inotify
/home/user/watched_directory: echo "hello again" > subdir/file2.txt // NOT registered
/home/user/watched_directory: mkdir subdir/subsubdir2               // NOT registered
```

As far as I understand inotify, any event of the kind specified at the creation of a watcher should be registered or am I missing something?

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 inside a docker container on a Windows host.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Ununtu 20 on Windows (WSL). Maybe you have too many [inotify watches](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13751/kernel-inotify-watch-limit-reached).

Answer (score 0):

Well, in response to a create node event, you need to check if it is a directory, and then add that directory to the list of monitored nodes.... The first time you navigate recursively your directory tree, adding all directories and subdirectories to the list of monitored nodes.... and you will receive the events.  As you see from the manual page, you receive information about the link created to the new inode child.  but you receive events only for the registered nodes, not for the indirectly connected nodes... imagine a machine with hundreds of users in session and each monitoring their home directory and having gigabytes of files... the kernel would explode.

If you accept a hint... don't do that.  If you are implementing a graphical desktop tool to view files like a desktop explorer or a file manager.... then notify only the directory under view... and nothing else... or you will tear down your system.